# How to cache requests in HTTP/2

Tags: http2

I'm developing a web application using Angular + Java, and I trying to improve performance with HTTP / 2 protocol. It's ok, but I do not have a significant performance improvement, as you can see:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfU14.png

The time to load a specific page is aproximatly the same. The difference is that using HTTP / 1.1, there is a caching resources. With HTTP / 2, there isn't caching, as we see bellow:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPNNC.png

Can I cache resources in HTTP/2 to load the page more fast?

Comment: Caching is no different under HTTP/2 than under HTTP/1. There is not enough information in the screenshot you have given to explain why this is happening.

Comment: I do not know what's happining. Maybe it's a feature of HTTP/2?

Comment: Nope. Are you sure you don’t have “disable cache” ticked? Add an example of a HTTP Request and Response for both to your question.

Comment: I don't had flaged the "disable cache". I figure out that IE and Firefox are caching resources, but Chrome not. I will try figure out why it's happining.

Comment: Ok. As I say if you include the Request and Response headers from one of the requests from developer tools it should be easy to spot if it’s sending and receiving the right cache headers.

Comment: It's a Chrome issue with certificates SSL self-signed . Chrome don't cache resources to self-signed certificates. Here's the bug explanation: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103875

Comment: Nice find! You should add this as an answer and accept it (accepting your own answer to your own question is fine). BTW, out of interest, is this any different under HTTP/1 and HTTP/2?

Comment: Regardless of the protocol version, HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2, the Chrome is not caching resources with self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Chrome issue with certificates SSL self-signed . Chrome don't cache resources to self-signed certificates. Here's the bug explanation: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103875